# Backing Up and Restoring Contacts from Microsoft Outlook on iOS 6

Tags: ios, iphone

I don't use Microsoft Outlook but when I backed up my iPhone 5 running iOS 6 on my laptop, it said the contacts from that application were backed up.

How do I find/check if the contacts are backed up and where are they stored?

Answer (score 1):

Launch Outlook and click the "Contacts" tab. You should see the imported iPhone contacts.

Read more: How to Copy Contacts From iPhone to Outlook | eHow.com http://www.ehow.com/how_5631494_copy-contacts-iphone-outlook.html#ixzz2J6aQOS5B